# Protect laravel api service with Okta and JWT

Tags: laravel, jwt, okta

Trying to put together a solution to protecting a Laravel 5.4 api using OKTA and JWT. I have an SPA that logs into my application via  OKTA and retrieves an access_token and id_token. It also passes this to API calls in the header using 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` but now i am struggling to find a solution to verify this access token with OKTA within the Laravel backend. been looking at tymon/jwt-auth but cant workout how to add a custom solution to verifiy the token but i would assume it can be done using okta/jwt-verifier does anyone have any samples/guide? also looked at laravel/socialite and socialiteproviders/okta but that seems more about a traditional backend login rather than an SPA

Answer (score 1):

Our `okta/jwt-verifier` library should be able to help you out here.  You will have to create a custom middleware solution to capture and authorize the request based on the bearer token.  Once you have that middleware set up, inside of the verifier library, you can run the following to verify the accessToken.

```
$jwtVerifier = (new \Okta\JwtVerifier\JwtVerifierBuilder())
    ->setAudience('api://default')
    ->setClientId('{clientId}')
    ->setIssuer('https://{yourOktaDomain}.com/oauth2/default')
    ->build();

$jwt = $jwtVerifier->verify($jwt);
```

By changing the client id and your okta domain above, you should be able to pass in the accessToken to the verify method.  If you do not get any exceptions, you can assume that the jwt is valid and approve the request.

See the [github repo readme](https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-php#usage) for information about what you have access to once you verify the validity of the JWT

Comment: thanks but doing exactly as you suggest but getting InvalidArgumentException: Unable to verify the JWS. in vendor/spomky-labs/jose/src/Verifier.php:146 Passing accessToken from oktaAuth.signIn checked clientId, Issuer etc and all valid

Comment: [
  {
    "idToken": "...",
    "expiresAt": ..,
    "scopes": [
      "openid",
      "email"
    ],
    "authorizeUrl": "https:\/\/dev-XXX.oktapreview.com\/oauth2\/v1\/authorize",
    "issuer": "https:\/\/dev-XXX.oktapreview.com",
    "clientId": "..."
  },
  {
    "accessToken": "...",
    "expiresAt": ...,
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
    "scopes": [
      "openid",
      "email"
    ],
    "authorizeUrl": "https:\/\/dev-XXX.oktapreview.com\/oauth2\/v1\/authorize",
    "userinfoUrl": "https:\/\/dev-XXX.oktapreview.com\/oauth2\/v1\/userinfo"
  }
]

Comment: You should be passing in the string version of the JWT, not the decoded version as you provided.

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this post. In the SPA make sure you also define the issuer, this should be a useful start...

```
//react login

this.oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({ 
  url: props.config.oktaUrl
  ,clientId:props.config.clientId
  ,redirectUri:props.config.redirectUri
  ,issuer: props.config.issuer
});
this.oktaAuth.signIn({
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
})
.then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        this.setState({
            sessionToken: response.sessionToken
        });
        this.oktaAuth.token.getWithoutPrompt({
            responseType: ['id_token', 'token']
            ,scopes: ['openid', 'email', 'profile']
            ,sessionToken: response.sessionToken
        })
        .then((tokenOrTokens) => {
            this.setState({
                tokenOrTokens: tokenOrTokens
            });
            window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', tokenOrTokens[1].accessToken);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        });
    }
})

//api call

const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null;

const config = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` 
  },
};

fetch(url, config)
    .then((response) => {
    ... 

//laravel api route

Route::group(['prefix' => 'restricted', 'middleware' => ['okta.validate']], function() {
    Route::get('/getprotecteddata', 'MyController@getProtectedData');
});

//laravel kernel.php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'okta.validate' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateOKTAToken::class,
];


//laravel middleware

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ValidateOKTAToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = $this->parseAuthHeader($request);
        $jwt = $this->validate($token);
        \Log::info("ValidateOKTAToken jwt=" . json_encode($jwt->toJson()));
        return $next($request);
    }


    protected function validate($token) {

        $oktaClientId = env('OKTA_CLIENTID');
        $oktaIssuer = env('OKTA_ISSUER');
        $oktaAudience = env('OKTA_AUDIENCE');

        $jwtVerifier = (new \Okta\JwtVerifier\JwtVerifierBuilder())
        ->setAudience($oktaAudience)
        ->setClientId($oktaClientId)
        ->setIssuer($oktaIssuer)
        ->build();

        $jwt = $jwtVerifier->verify($token);
        return $jwt;        
    }

    protected function parseAuthHeader(Request $request, $header = 'authorization', $method = 'bearer')
    {
        $header = $request->headers->get($header);

        if (! starts_with(strtolower($header), $method)) {
            return false;
        }

        return trim(str_ireplace($method, '', $header));
    }
}
```